# Pandas unique not returning all unique values when data is binary

Tags: python, pandas

I have noticed some unusual behaviour when using the `unique()` function on a column of binary data where not all values are returned.

```
R = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.choice([10. , 20., 30.], size=20), columns=['A'])
R.loc[:, 'B'] = R.A.apply(lambda x: struct.pack('f', x))
print len(R.A.unique()), len(R.B.unique()), len(np.unique(R.B))
print R.B.unique(), np.unique(R.B)
```

which returns

```
3 1 3
['\x00\x00 A'] ['\x00\x00 A' '\x00\x00\xa0A' '\x00\x00\xf0A']
```

When running `R.B.value_count()` three values are returned.

The `dtype` of `R.B` is `dtype('O')`.

I am using Pandas version `0.21.0`

Comment: Tested in `pandas 0.22.0`  `python 3.5` under `win` and working nice.

Comment: returned `3 3 3`
`[b'\x00\x00\xa0A' b'\x00\x00\xf0A' b'\x00\x00 A'] [b'\x00\x00 A' b'\x00\x00\xa0A' b'\x00\x00\xf0A']`